# I can't get access token for my facebook app

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, access-token

I want to get the `access_token` for my app. This is a Laravel project. I use `HttpClient` for request. Do request like in instruction but its return me - `error 'Missing redirect_uri parameter'`.

```
$access_token = [
    'url'=>'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token/',
    'params'=>[
        'client_id'=> env('FACEBOOK_KEY'),
        'client_secret'=> env('FACEBOOK_SECRET'),
        'grant_type'=> 'client_credentials',
    ]
];

$response = HttpClient::get($access_token)->json();
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Laravel Socialite. This is a package made by Laravel to handle oAuth2 with Facebook (and other apps).

See: [laravel/socialite](https://github.com/laravel/socialite)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.